# Java program stuck after "for" loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

My Java program seems to be stuck after a `for-loop`. It is not stuck in the loop, but the program just simply does not want to go further for some reason. It completes the loop successfully however:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] command = new String[20];
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; a.hasNext(); i++) {
        command[i] = a.next();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    a.close();
    System.out.println("asd");
}
```

This program prints out `"0"` if you entered 1 word, `"0 1"` if 2, and so on, but the `System.out.println("asd")` never executes, and also, the program never stops.

Comment: change `a.hasNext();` by `i < command.length;`

Comment: Didn't do the trick, problem persists, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you show us your error please? If you try the code of [Nikolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028619/5558072) I'm sure this will not cause any problem

Comment: I don't have any runtime errors or anything else, the code just wont stop running, but the for-loop executes just fine. Happens the same with Nikolas's solution

Comment: @Oceanis: Since you can with `System.in`, you have to provide an input to the console - do you? The program stops at `command[i] = a.next()` line until an input appears.

Comment: What exactly is the requirement here? Do you want your code to stop after the user enters one input? The code terminates with an exception if you enter more than 20 words.

Comment: @Nikolas I do, and the loop does what i want it to do. If I enter "asd asd asd" the program prints out 0 1 2, if I enter "asd asd asd asd", the program prints out 0 1 2 3. Just the parts after the for loop are never executing.

Comment: Learn the difference between `Scanner::next` and `Scanner::nextLine` which terminates the line - I think this might be the issue.

Comment: @Oceanis: If you keep running the code, after the second user input the counter starts off from the last value. So after you enter "asd asd asd asd" the program would print 3 4 5 6

Comment: @NicholasK I want the program to run, because the problem here is that it just stops after the for loop, outputting an increasingly higher number after each word I entered, but the program does not stop with any error, it just stays running, not giving any output anymore.

Comment: @Nikolas If I'd use nextLine, the program would store the whole line in as a string in command[0]. However, i want to store each word in the command array (1st word: command[0], 2nd: command[1], and so on)

Comment: @NicholasK Also, I don't know what's that second input you are talking about, the program runs once, with one input.

Comment: @Oceanis: If you want to store each word in an array index, just use `String[] command = input.split(" ");`

Comment: @Oceanis: Your for loop is always true so it constantly allows the user to read values till you receive an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @NicholasK I guess that would definitely fix the problem, but I want to understand what is the real problem here. Because if the loop would be infinite, and would keep on going, it would print out constantly something, but it stops where I expect it to stop.

Comment: @NicholasK I don't receive any exception. Looks like the loop just stops, and the program also stops, but keeps running.

Comment: Try this input and let me know what happens according to you. First enter "a b c", hit enter and after that enter "x y z". I'm sure the code is allowing you to enter these values. Just want to see how you are running it. Your output should be"0 1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: The loop doesn't stop, its waiting for your input again.

Comment: @NicholasK Ah I see now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because the program was waiting for your input again, it was never stuck. Also, your code would terminate with an exception (`ArrayOutOfBoundException`) only once the size of the array is exceeded i.e user entered more than 20 tokens.

If you want to capture each word in index of an array, use

`String[] command = a.split(" ");`

which will even avoid that for loop that caused the unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

The execution of `for-loop` never ends because `a.hasNext()` is always `true`. So the loop never meets a condition for the termination. For this reason, you have to use `break` at some point (input is ex. `"EXIT"`) to get out the endless loop or set the max allowed `i` - haven't you mean `command.length` to fill the array up with values?

```
for (int i = 0; i < command.length; i++) {
    command[i] = a.next();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program never terminates because `System.in` is never closed, thus `hasNext()` will always be true and the loop will never end.

Instead you can ask the user to enter a specific character to quit the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] command = new String[20];
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; a.hasNext(); i++) {
            command[i] = a.next();
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");
            if(a.next().equals("n")){
                break;
            }
        }
        a.close();
        System.out.println("asd");
    }
```

Comment: There was no requirement in the question to terminate the loop

Answer (score 0):

check exit condition in for loop

`!a.next().equals("n")`

```
//

public static void main(String args[])

     {

        String[] command = new String[20];
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; a.hasNext() && !a.next().equals("n"); i++) {
            command[i] = a.next();
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");

        }
        a.close();       

     }
```

Comment: There was no requirement in the question to terminate the loop